# Xcode 4 with iOS 5 very slow debugging

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I am experiencing very slow debugging in Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0.Here is something getting printed in the console.Any known reasons for that?

"warning: No copy of ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session"

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your project and change the optimization level in your target settings to none. See if that works.